# casting dates in postgresql for a date_time field

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to fetch records from a `postgres` database between 2 `dates`
So am using this query
date_time is the name of a `date_time` column in db. When I try to fetch records the last date wont gets fetched as its a datetime field

```
sql_query = '''SELECT * FROM {} WHERE date_time BETWEEN '{}'  and '{}' ORDER BY date_time'''.format(some_table_name, start_date, end_date)
```

so I casted dates like this.

```
sql_query = '''SELECT * FROM {} WHERE CAST([date_time] as DATE)  BETWEEN '{}'  and '{}' ORDER BY date_time'''.format(some_table_name, start_date, end_date)
raw_data_df = pd.read_sql((sql_query), engine)
```

But now am getting a syntax error

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM some_table_name WHERE CAST([date_time] as DATE)  BETWEEN '...
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Postgres uses double quotes, not square brackets, to quote identifiers. But `date_time` doesn't need quoting anyway - `CAST(date_time AS DATE)` will not throw a syntax error.

Comment: @AdamKG Thank you. That was the issue. Fixed. If you provide this as an answer I can accept.